# Span element change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is:

Does have a span element the inner html change event? 
I think about I have a span and when the span inner html is changing it will throw an event that I can reach?

I would like to use Jquery to bind to this event of span.

l.

Answer (score 6):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element
>   when its value changes. This event is
>   limited to `<input>` elements,
>   `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements.

Comment: Spans don't have values in the first place…

Comment: The question is a bit cryptic, but he would like a change event when the inner html of <span> tag changes.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, such events are not supported by browsers like IE, but what you are looking for is DOM events. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM_Events for more information.

Answer (score 1):

No. As a rule of thumb, if something internal to a script changes something, it will not trigger an event.

Nothing external to a script can edit the innerHTML of a span (unless, perhaps, it is contentEditable) so there is no event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handle it when you make the change?

```
function updateHTML(el,newhtml,callback){
    el.innerHTML=newhtml;
    if(typeof callback=='function')callback(el);
}
```