# Monitor change of contenteditable span?

Tags: jquery

I have a `span` with `contenteditable="true"`. Im trying to attach a `change` event to it. But according the jQuery docs, change only works for form inputs. Any other way?

Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vQuEA/

Comment: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949908/span-element-change-event  , in some browsers you can monitor a change in DOM , that might slow things down , there may be a better way

Comment: @ScottSelby That just says what i already know, that change is limited to form elements. Im trying to find a different method

Comment: you can't use a button ?  or text input? or use any other event to monitor the html of the span?

Comment: @ScottSelby I could user another event to monitor the html of the span. But i dont know any, thats my reason for the question..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this block to your page:

```
$('[contenteditable]').on('focus', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('before', $this.html());
    return $this;
}).on('blur keyup paste', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('before') !== $this.html()) {
        $this.data('before', $this.html());
        $this.trigger('change');
    }
    return $this;
});
```

It will cause a `change` event to fire whenever a tag with `contenteditable` is changed.

**Explanation**

All elements that have a `contenteditable` attribute will receive event listeners for `focus`, `blur`, `keyup`, and `paste`.

During `focus` the current inner html is stored as 'before' data on the element.

During `blur` / `keyup` / `paste` the current inner html is compared to the 'before' data and if it is different a `change` event is triggered.

Comment: Explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems to work. Not sure if it's a new thing since these other answers, but it's a lot cleaner:

```
contentEditableTag.on('input', function(){
    console.log("input event");
});
```

Fires on every keystroke, including pastes.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/makesites/jquery-contenteditable

> jQuery contentEditable
>   Automatically adds events on 'contenteditable' fields and returns the
>   changed data for further processing (and saving)
>
> Usage
>
> In its basic implementation, the plugin method contentEditable() is
>   attached to the parent container that has all the 'contenteditable'
>   fields.

```
$("#...").contentEditable().change( myFunction );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[contenteditable]').focusout(function() {
  var span = $(this);
  var statuses = ['bd-danger', 'bd-warning', 'bd-success'];
  statuses.forEach(function(s) {
    span.hasClass(s) ? span.removeClass(s) : '';
  })
  if (span.html().trim()) {
    if (span.html() === span.data('initial')) {
      span.addClass('bd-warning');
    } else {
      span.addClass('bd-success');
    }
  } else {
    span.addClass('bd-danger');
  }
});
```

```css
.bd-danger {
  border: 1px #e81c22 solid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bd-warning {
  border: 1px #fbc658 solid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.bd-success {
  border: 1px #04ad36 solid;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <span contenteditable="true" data-initial="Edit this content">Edit this content</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer to the question.  Code-only answers are discouraged on SO.  Please consider providing some context around your answer to help others understand why your solution solves the problem.