# how to get value of contenteditable element into jquery

Tags: php

```
$("#txt1").change(function()
{
     alert(this.value);
});
<span id="txt1" contenteditable="true"> </span>
```

I have to work with php and i edit dynamically data into my table like datatable, when change my content nothing event occurred.

Comment: `<span>`s cannot have automatically triggered change events. They also don't have `value` properties. To get the content of the span, use `$('#txt1').html()` or `$('#txt1').text()`, depending on your needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor change of contenteditable span?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027153/monitor-change-of-contenteditable-span)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.change()` event is not available for span elements. From jQuery's `.change()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> This event is limited to **input** elements, **textarea** boxes and
>   **select** elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons,
>   the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with
>   the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until
>   the element loses focus.